# Why does accessing the component method yield in undefined when accessing it from getDefaultProps()?

Tags: reactjs

I have a custom `typeahead` component that I am trying to modify & I want to pass down a custom `onBlur` method from parent to child.

I have `getDefaultProps` defined in case `onBlur` isn't passed on:

```
  getDefaultProps: function () {
    console.log(this.handleBlur) // undefined
    return {
      onChange: function () {},
      onBlur: this.handleBlur
    }
  }
```

`handleBlur` is a method inside the component that I want to access. How would I access a method inside the component there?

Answer (score 0):

Internally React get's the default props before the Class is instanciated. That means the getDefaultProps function is a static method of the class. If you create your react components with `createReactClass` it is not that obvious that it is a static method.

There are different Ways of creating static functions or variables in javascript:

```js
// 1. Old JS:
function Foo() {}
Foo.staticFunction = function(){}
var foo = new Foo();
// typeof Foo.staticFunction === 'function'
// typeof foo.staticFunction === 'undefined'

// 2. ES6:
class Foo {
    static myFunction = () => { ... }
}
```

When you are using ES6 you could write something like

```js
// add the onBlur function outside of the class scope
const handleBlur = event => { /*  your fallback blur handler */ }

class MyComponent extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        handleChange() {},
        handleBlur,
    };
}
```

Another way would be to set the blurHandler inside the constructor function:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context)

        if (!this.props.blurHandler) {
            this.blurHandler = this.defaultBlurHandler
        }
    }
    defaultBlurHandler = () => { /* do your stuff here */ }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we are not using ES6 classes in our code base.